# Different colors for all cells of all columns in dt package

Tags: r, gt

I would like to make a simple table and add different specific background color to different values of all cells (if 0 then color x1, if between 0 and 20 then color x2, if between 21-40 then color x3 etc.). I couldn't find out how this works except of going through each and every column in my dataframe. How can I refer to all cells in all columns instead of going through column1 (see below) then add column2, column3 etc...? I dont want a heat table because I need to exactly specifiy my color values

```
library(gt)

testdf = data.frame(
  Column1 = c(0,80,3,10,100),
  Column2 = c(0,50,80,2,55)
)

gt_tbl <- testdf %>% 
  gt() %>% 
  tab_style(
    style = list(
      cell_fill(color = "red"),
      cell_text(weight = "normal")
    ),
    locations = cells_body(
      columns = vars(Column1),
      rows = Column1 == 0)
  ) %>% 
  tab_style(
    style = list(
      cell_fill(color = "blue"),
      cell_text(weight = "normal")
    ),
    locations = cells_body(
      columns = vars(Column1),
      rows = Column1 > 0 & Column1 < 20)
  )

  
gt_tbl
```

Answer (score 2):

This could be achieved using `add_css_conditional_column` from the `tableHTML` package. it allows to apply certain css to fields in the table, when a condition applies:

```r
library(tableHTML)

testdf = data.frame(
 Column1 = c(0,80,3,10,100),
 Column2 = c(0,50,80,2,55)
)

testdf %>% 
 tableHTML(rownames=FALSE,
           widths = c(100, 100)) %>% 
 # add_theme("rshiny-blue") %>% # optional, if predefined theme is desired
 add_css_conditional_column(conditional = "==",
                            value = 0,
                            css = list("background-color",
                                       "red"),
                            columns = 1:2) %>%
 add_css_conditional_column(conditional = "between",
                            between = c(1, 20),
                            css = list("background-color",
                                       "blue"),
                            columns = 1:2) %>% 
 add_css_conditional_column(conditional = "between",
                            between = c(21, 40),
                            css = list("background-color",
                                       "green"),
                            columns = 1:2)
```

The result is:

[image: tableHTML_result]

Comment: thank you :) looks great, but I need to export as a pdf...

Comment: You could use tableHTML_to_image to include the table in a pdf. But that's only a workaround